# SQL Query > sysdate <Sysdate + 1 year

Tags: sql, sysdate

I am trying to write a query that will find the max expiration date but what i noticed is when I am doing this I get no results if I have a  expiration date  lets say 30-Dec-16 and for the same part I also have an expiration date of 01-Jan-2099 (which is the default date if nothing is filled in) below is my query how could I rewrite the expiration_date query to get the correct date.

```
SELECT 
 Part,
 price,
 effective_date,
 expiration_date
FROM a.Table 
 WHERE Part IN ('&Part') 
 AND PRICE  IN ('somewere') 
 AND expiration_date IN (SELECT 
                          MAX(expiration_date) 
                          FROM table  
                          WHERE expiration_date > SYSDATE 
                          AND  part IN ('&Part)  
                          AND PRICE IN (Somewere)) 
 AND to_date(effective_date) IN (SELECT 
                                  MAX(EFFECTIVE_DATE) FROM b.table  
                                  WHERE expiration_date > SYSDATE 
                                  AND  Part IN ('&Part)  
                                  AND price  IN (somewere) 
                                  AND EFFECTIVE_DATE < SYSDATE + 1)
```

Comment: Sample data from each of the tables along with desired results would help.

Comment: Add more info including samples and the expected output!

Comment: Sorry I forgot to Pull out that inner Join I do not need that. sample data is as follows:   Apples 7.95   1-Dec-16       30-Dec-16                                    Apples 7.95   1-Nov-16       30-Nov-16                                                    Apples 7.95   30-Dec-16       01-Jan-2099             I am looking for it to give me  This for the results  Apples 7.95   1-Dec-16       30-Dec-16

Answer (score 0):

I would use ROW_NUMBER. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm

Here is the query:

```
SELECT
    part
    ,price
    ,effective_date
    ,expieration_date
FROM (
    SELECT
        part
        ,price
        ,effective_date
        ,expieration_date
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY part ORDER BY expieration_date DESC) AS "row"
    FROM @tbl
    WHERE effective_date < SYSDATE + 1
    ) tbl
WHERE "row" = 1
```

Here is what I used to populate @tbl.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (
part NVARCHAR(MAX)
,price FLOAT
,effective_date DATETIME2(3)
,expieration_date DATETIME2(3)
)

INSERT @tbl (part, PRICE, EFFECTIVE_DATE, EXPIERATION_DATE)
VALUES ('Apples',7.95,'2016-12-01','2016-12-30')
    ,('Apples',7.95,'2016-11-01','2016-11-30')
    ,('Apples',7.95,'2016-12-30','2099-01-01')
```

Comment: I am getting "From keyword not found were expected" on the ROW_NUM line

Comment: I am running my query in oracle sql developer

Comment: Sorry, Oracle SQL Developer requires "" when declaring column names. Updated the query. As long as you replace @tbl with your table, everything else should work.